# JMeter SOAP/XML-RPC request with URL built from property not being expanded

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, jmeter

I'm using the SOAP/XML-RPC sampler and I want to be able to have a variable hostname in the URL and SOAPAction headers.

I have tried passing in on the command line (-Jhost=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) and expanding using ${__P(host)} but it seems to be null (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null) when I run the test.

I use other properties passed on the command line in the XML body which are successfully expanded.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Any news on that, was my answer OK ? If your issue is confirmed you should open a bug on JMeter Bugzilla

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me:

in URL field I put :

```
http://${__P(host)}:8888/test
```

When launching in GUI, I add:

```
-Jhost=localhost
```

Works with JMeter 2.7 and current trunk , I didn't test with previous versions.

Can you give more details ?

- What you have in test plan
- The full exception stack trace in jmeter.log

Regards

Philippe M.